# Build simple programm with freetype lib on windows via cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, freetype

I'm trying to build a simple application
using the freetype library on  Windows 64.
Freetype lib was compiled from src on windows 64

simple programm

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

FT_Library ft;
  if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft) != 0) {
    //err
  }
}
```

Added environment variable FREETYPE_DIR
and cmake script

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

cmake_path(CONVERT $ENV{COMPILER} TO_CMAKE_PATH_LIST COMPILER)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${COMPILER}/clang++.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${COMPILER}/clang.exe")
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER "${COMPILER}/llvm-rc.exe")

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "../bin")

project (text)
file(GLOB SRC 
"./src/main.cpp"
)

find_package(Freetype MODULE REQUIRED)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
  PRIVATE "./include" 
  PRIVATE ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}

 Freetype::Freetype
)
```

but I'm stuck, get a linker error, although freetype library is linked

```
ninja: Entering directory `./build'
[1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd . && 
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE -fuse-ld=lld-link 
-nostartfiles -nostdlib -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt - 
Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/text.dir/src/main.cpp.obj -o 
D:\git\cpp\opengl\drawtext\bin\text.exe -Xlinker /MANIFEST:EMBED -Xlinker 
/implib:D:\git\cpp\opengl\drawtext\bin\text.lib -Xlinker 
/pdb:D:\git\cpp\opengl\drawtext\bin\text.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   D:/source/freetype- 
2.12.1/build/x86_64/Release/lib/freetype.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool - 
lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames  && cd ."
FAILED: D:/git/cpp/opengl/drawtext/bin/text.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && 
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2022\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE -fuse-ld=lld-link 
-nostartfiles -nostdlib -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt - 
Xlinker /subsystem:console CMakeFiles/text.dir/src/main.cpp.obj -o 
D:\git\cpp\opengl\drawtext\bin\text.exe -Xlinker /MANIFEST:EMBED -Xlinker 
/implib:D:\git\cpp\opengl\drawtext\bin\text.lib -Xlinker 
/pdb:D:\git\cpp\opengl\drawtext\bin\text.pdb -Xlinker /version:0.0   D:/source/freetype- 
2.12.1/build/x86_64/Release/lib/freetype.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool - 
lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -loldnames  && cd ."
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: FT_Init_FreeType
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/text.dir/src/main.cpp.obj:(main)
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: "Freetype lib was compiled from src on windows 64" - Which **compiler** you have used for build Freetype library? Your project is being built with clang, so it unlikely would work with Freetype build with other compiler.

Comment: Freetype lib build with clang 13.0. And app with clang++ 13.0

Answer (score 0):

Find the workaround, recompile freetype lib via Microsoft cl.exe instead of clang.